# apache thrift transport TTransportException

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Hive Version : 0.13.1

Pig Version  : 0.13.0

I was trying to get read the hive tables using pig with the below command.

```
grunt> DATA = LOAD 'dev.profile' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

I get the below piece of log

```
2014-07-16 22:44:58,986 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
2014-07-16 22:44:59,037 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:10000
2014-07-16 22:44:59,057 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
2014-07-16 22:45:02,019 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
2014-07-16 22:45:02,166 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
```

when i do the describe the results comes properly as expected.

```
grunt> describe DATA
2014-07-16 22:46:42,189 [main] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - DEPRECATED: hive.metastore.ds.retry.* no longer has any effect.  Use hive.hmshandler.retry.* instead
DATA: {name: chararray,age: int,salary: int}
```

but when i dump the data i get SocketTimeoutException

```
2014-07-16 22:47:25,146 [main] ERROR hive.log - Got exception: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_databases(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_databases(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getDatabases(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:826)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.isOpen(HiveClientCache.java:276)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:146)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:548)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.getHiveMetaClient(PigHCatUtil.java:158)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.getTable(PigHCatUtil.java:200)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.getSchema(HCatLoader.java:195)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:89)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:885)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3568)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1712)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1420)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1004)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:974)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:887)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:752)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:228)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:542)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 40 more
2014-07-16 22:47:25,148 [main] ERROR hive.log - Converting exception to MetaException
2014-07-16 22:47:25,151 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:10000
2014-07-16 22:47:25,152 [main] INFO  hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
2014-07-16 22:47:45,173 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader
Failed to parse: Can not retrieve schema from loader org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader@1342464f
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1712)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1420)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:1004)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:974)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:887)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:752)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:228)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:203)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:542)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not retrieve schema from loader org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader@1342464f
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:91)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:885)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3568)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:179)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:89)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.getTable(PigHCatUtil.java:205)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.getSchema(HCatLoader.java:195)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1036)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.get_table(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1022)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:997)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getTable(HCatUtil.java:194)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.getTable(PigHCatUtil.java:201)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 37 more
2014-07-16 22:47:45,176 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2245: Cannot get schema from loadFunc org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader
```

Even though i am able to connect to metastore i am not able to retrieve the data. What could be the reason for read fail ? 
and at times the process fails with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the hive-site.xml.
Replace `hive.metastore.ds.retry` with `/hive.hmshandler.retry`.

```
vim /usr/local/Cellar/hive/0.13.1/libexec/conf/hive-site.xml
:%s/hive.metastore.ds.retry/hive.hmshandler.retry/g
:wq
```